# Log4J could not find a logging implementation

Tags: java, log4j

I made a console App to migrate data from Solr to Elastic Search. The App works OK, just the logger is giving me problems. **It works fine when I run the App in IntelliJ but it doesn't when I compile and run on the command line.**

Error message: `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...`

This is the command I use to run on the command line `java -cp analytics.jar org.example.App`.

These are the dependencies from my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

My imports:

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

And how I instantiate the logger:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",appPath.concat("/log4j.properties"));
log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());


try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(appPath.concat("/log4j.properties")));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've been trying answers from similar questions here on Stack Overflow and none has worked for me.

Comment: The error tells you that you need to add `log4j-core` to the classpath. So happens if you add `log4j-core.jar` to your `-cp` command - like `-cp analytics.jar;/path/to/log4j-core.jar`?

Comment: When you run it in the IntelliJ - the terminal/command line that opens shows the entire classpath that it uses... make sure you use a similar command yourself as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
java -cp "analytics.jar;log4j-core-2.11.1.jar" org.example.App
```

`log4j-core-2.11.1.jar` is in the same folder of analytics.jar